# Google Cloud Storage OAuth cross project access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

Are OAuth user credentials in Google Cloud limited to the project in which the OAuth client ID exists or is it across the whole Google Cloud?

For example:

If there are two projects **P1** and **P2**.

**P1** has a bucket **B1** and **P2** has a bucket **B2**.

**P1** defines an OAuth client ID for user credentials. The scope of this client ID is read-write to buckets.

A client uses this client ID in **P1** and authenticates some user called Alice and gets an access token.

Assuming Alice has access to both buckets **B1** and **B2**. Will this token also have access to both the buckets **B1** and **B2**?

Comment: If Alice has the permission on the bucket, the same token works for both. It's not a matter of token, it's a matter of permission with Cloud IAM

Comment: Identities issued/managed by Google Accounts work across all Google and Google Cloud services.  https://accounts.google.com There are other types of identities as well that have other requirements.

Comment: Cloud Storage uses [OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth) for API authentication and authorization. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes) you can learn more about the scope. To obtain an access token from the Google Authorization Server, you can [read this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server).